# Check if a pair of values is already used and dont allow entering differenet pair that shares one of the values with already used pair

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, constraints

I have MS ACCESS 2010 database that I made for some of my co-workers. The purpose of the database is to gather manual information in more automated way about some employees (instead of emailing files or having to rely on buggy excel sharing features).

I managed to make sure that each user see only their own data using query as a mean of interfacing with user and checking windows api to get user name.

Now I have a specific problem that I don't know how to solve:

Table contains of 3 columns that user have to enter manually:

```
ID
Name
Location
```

ID is not ID of this table, its an ID from totally different system that I can not interface with so it have to be manually entered along with name as I need it later. ID is unique for each employee.

Now I made sure that user can not enter unique combination of those three columns twice using constrains (the same name/id can be used for different locations), but what is possible is that user enter the same ID with different name (not good), or the same name with different ID (possible as employees may have the same name).

Is there a way to check upon entering of data if a given ID exists with different name then the one entered by the user?

Example:

```
ID   NAME   LOCATION
123  Martin Warszawa - OK
123  Martin Kraków   - OK (the same person assigned to his second location)
124  Martin Kraków   - OK (same name as another guy from Kraków, but two different persons)
123  Paul   Wrocław  - NOT OK (ID points to Martin, so it should not be entered as Paul)
123  Martin Warszawa - NOT OK (duplicated first row - blocked with constrains)
```

Can this even be accomplished?

What I would want to retain is the ability to enter values by users in the query window and this as far as I know will be compromised if I change this into One:Many table relationship.

I assume that macro/sql procedure could be used to accomplish that and block insert attempt but I don't know how to accomplish it

Comment: Can you just add unique constraints on ID and Name individually? they each need to be unique independantly from the sounds of things. if this messes with your 3 column unique constrain I am not sure that one is required as easch name or ID can only be there once so therefore will only ever have one location assigned.

Comment: @gordatron Neither ID nor Name should be Unique. both can show up multiple times. Even pair ID > Name can be used multiple times with different value of Location, but if I have pair ID1 > Name1 I can not have ID1 > Name2

Comment: @Fionnuala Assuming that the proper constrain is in place from the start there is only one valid name for each ID in table when I try to enter data for new row.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize your database. You have users identified by an ID (primary key bold):

- users (**id**, name)

and their locations:

- user_locations (**user_id, location**)

So there can be no longer be duplicate user entries and there can be no duplicate locations. If you want to add something, use INSERT. If that fails, it means the entry is already there. If you want to update something, use UPDATE. If you want to insert or update depending, try INSERT first; if this fails UPDATE. (You can search for *upsert* and MS-Access, and you will find how this is done).

Comment: Yes this is the right choice however this will make project much bigger than it should. Once I go into One:Many relationships I can no longer use Queries to allow user to input data, I will have to rely on a forms which adds to complexity. What I am looking for is a way to run check inputed value against result of some query "before insert/update". I see no way of adding triggers in ACCESS (it does not recognize query syntax). Right now I'm looking into Data Macros as solution, will update if I find something.